# Complete Python reference

Tags: python

Does Python language has a solid reference page somewhere. For example, I would like to inspect Python.Test.Client class - see its methods and fields.

The only reference I found is https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html

But it doesn't contain information about Client.

May be someone can share sources that they use.

Comment: Maybe using the [`inspect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html), or `help()` in an interpreter ?

Comment: What is `Python.Test.Client`?

Comment: The [standard library `test`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html) doesn't have a `Client` class. Are you using some third-party library (e.g. there's a [`django.test.Client`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client))?

Comment: If you want python repos they are under https://hg.python.org/releasing, but boy, I can't find `Python.Test.Client` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try [IPython](http://ipython.org/) for exploring. 
There you can for example do the following:

```
In [1]: import unittest
In [2]: unittest?
```

Which will give you the output

```
Type:        module
String form: <module 'unittest' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__init__.pyc'>
File:        /usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__init__.py
Docstring:
Python unit testing framework, based on Erich Gamma's JUnit and Kent Beck's
Smalltalk testing framework.

This module contains the core framework classes that form the basis of
specific test cases and suites (TestCase, TestSuite etc.), and also a
text-based utility class for running the tests and reporting the results
 (TextTestRunner).

Simple usage:
...
```

And if you append `??` instead of `?` you will even get more information. 
And if you're still not satisfied you can have a look in the source code directly because you can see the file in which the function/module/class in question is at the top of the output.

Also the tab completion is nice, you should try it :)